# EF Core6 RawQuery Update Table Column no matter conccurency

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am having C# project using Entity Framework Core 6.0.6 I have the following scenario:
I have tournaments which have start date and end date. I have players wallets which have column TournamentId pointing to the tournament table. I want to set TournamentId = Null to all players after the tournament finishes ignoring any possible concurrency conflicts. What is the best practice to achieve this.
This is my Tournament definition:

```
 public class Tournament
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public TournamentType Type { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my Wallet definition:

```
   public class Wallet
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
        public decimal Available { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public int? TournamentId { get; set; }
    }
```

in the mean time Total and available could change because may continue playing.

my code to make the change is the following:

```
private async Task ClosePlayerTournaments()
        {
            var query = "Update Wallets Set TournamentId = null";
            _context.Wallets.FromSqlRaw(query);

            var saved = false;
            while (!saved)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Attempt to save changes to the database
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    saved = true;
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
                {
                    // Log error
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ExecuteSqlAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#executing-non-querying-sql)
 or [ExecuteSqlRawAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlrawasync?view=efcore-7.0) and don't call `SaveChanges` :

```
private async Task ClosePlayerTournaments()
{
    var query = "Update Wallets Set TournamentId = null";
    await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(query);
}
```

or

```
private async Task ClosePlayerTournaments()
{
    await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlAsync($"Update Wallets Set TournamentId = null");
}
```

`SaveChanges` persists all changes made to tracked objects, ie objects loaded through a DbContext or attached to it. If it detects that the underlying data was changed by someone else, even another connection in the same application, it will raise a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`

**EF Core 7**

In EF Core 7 the raw SQl query can be replaced by [ExecuteUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#basic-executeupdate-examples) :

```
await _context.Wallets.ExecuteUpdateAsync(
    s => s.SetProperty(b => b.TournamentId , null);
```

Comment: I guess you mean ExecuteSqlRawAsync?

Comment: Oops, it's `_context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync` or `_context.Database.ExecuteSqlAsync`